# Meaning of "long gone"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-usage

*The first artifacts were just wooden poles which have *long gone*, but these were raised by men in times so ancient*

I can't understand what "long gone" means here.

Comment: *Which have long gone* means "which have disappeared long ago". A wooden pole is a pole made of wood. Google it.

Comment: There is nothing mysterious about "wooden poles."  You can look these words up in a dictionary.  "Long gone," on the other hand, might be on-topic.  I'm removing the "wooden poles" reference. I'll let the community decide what to do with "long gone."

Comment: I have a hunch that this is talking about Stonehenge, am I correct?

Comment: This question might be a better fit for our proposed sister site for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2). Please support it. Thank you.

Comment: @ArlenBeiler yes, that's correct

Comment: @KitFox I never added wooden poles reference here. I intended to ask for long gone in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the materials referenced are not very durable, they have broken down and no longer exist. The term *gone* is used to indicate that they no longer exist in a meaningful form. According to [Compact Oxford English Dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gone?view=uk), *gone* means

> no longer present; departed:

*Long* is an adverb modifying gone.  It means *long ago* or *a long time*.  It has been a significant period of time since the materials could be seen.

Comment: But, generally speaking, problems are not rooted in misunderstandings ('long ago' != 'a long time') by distorting or forgetting what words actually mean in everyday use! Furthermore, as far as I concern, you get into trouble by trying to understand words outside of the context of their use in spoken language, as - precisely - the OP said! That being said, I cannot vote up this answer!

Comment: I appreciate everyone's participation. I got it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell for sure with just this little bit, but I'll give it a shot. Context is always important in English. Wooden poles should be pretty self explanatory, so I'll save my breath. Seriously, a picture is worth a thousand words. Most likely it means the wooden poles have long gone, but they were raised so long ago (so far in the distant past) that this is understandable.

Comment: You may need to edit your answer (since the question has been edited), so that you don't define "long gone" as "long gone"!